# Unselected UIPickerView value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uipickerview

According to the documentation, if a UIPickerView has no selected value, the expected return from selectedRowInComponent: should be:

> "A zero-indexed number identifying the selected row, or -1 if no row is selected."

However, if I check the value the very line after initializing one, its value is 0.  Even if I then manually set it to -1, it still returns 0.  I would like to be able to detect whether the user has chosen a value yet or not, without recording it in a local variable.  Is this possible?

example:

```
UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 46.0, 320.0, 216.0)];
[picker selectRow:-1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
NSLog(@"SELECTED %d", [picker selectedRowInComponent:0]);

expected output:
SELECTED -1

actual output:
SELECTED 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think it will return -1 only if the component requested doesn't actually have any rows in it.  There's no way to *not* have a row selected in a `UIPickerView`.  I mean, you could have an empty row at the top, or something, and that would be index 0, but there's no way to tell the `UIPickerView` to not select any of the rows.

Comment: I suppose that's the answer, but I would argue that either the documentation or the code is broken.  The docs seem to clearly indicate that it supports a "no selection" mode, and says nothing about this just meaning there are no rows.

Comment: I don't think this is entirely true. In my case I have five items in my list and I set it to -1 when the picker opens. If the user clicks on a row it sets to that value, but if they don't, I do get -1 back. It seems that -1 really means "there was no interaction with the list"

Comment: Based on my observations, a picker view will return 0 even when it has no rows. I haven't been able to figure out under what circumstances it would actually return -1.